# Ошибка "window is not defined" при использовании Web Workers

Tags: jquery, webworkers, javascript, html5

Привет.

В общем хочу, чтобы Web Workers подгружал jQuery. Когда он загрузит, то выполнить код ...

```
<input type="text" value="" onblur="sayHi(this.value)" />
<input type="button" value="Можно кликать по запрос обрабатывается"  onclick="alert('click')"  />

<output id="result"></output>

<script>
    function sayHi(text) {
        worker.postMessage(text);
    }
    var worker = new Worker('1.js');

    worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        document.getElementById('result')
            .innerHTML = e.data;
        $("input").css('color', 'red');
    }, false);
</script>
```

1,js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    importScripts('jquery/jquery.js');
    var data = e.data;
    j = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        j = j + 1
    }
    var gt = j + data;
    self.postMessage('DATA IS: ' + gt);

}, false);
```

Выдает ошибку **window is not defined;**

Comment: ХэшКод создай метку WebWorkers

Comment: это может сделать не только @Хэшкод :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

скорее всего ошибка возникает при подключении jquery, window, в контексте web worker-ов не доступен

Comment: я прописал window=self,тогда уже другая ошибка.Это логично подключать jquery через WW или это бред?

Comment: Именно такой вопрос и нужно было задавать - это полный бред :)

Comment: ну это пример ради теста.Думал что выйдет...

Comment: WW, в основном, используются для любого рода интенсивных вычислений, т.е., первоочередная цель даже не производительность в плане времени выполнения той или иной операции, а доступность UI (e.g. не заблокированный event loop). Быть может я ошибаюсь, но, как мне показалось, вы немного недопонимаете зачем вообще он нужен...

Comment: если чесно так еще не полностю разобрался...
Ну я понимаю что вычислять выражения типа 2 в 4567 степени лучше через его,потому что браузер будет долго висеть...А вот что еще делать можно его?Читал что он не имееет доступа к Dom ,но есть XMLHTTPREQUEST.Как его можно заюзать?

Comment: @koza4ok запомните простую истину - пока нет реально тяжелых вычислений вам не нужны WW